# How can I redirect users to exam page in javascript?

Tags: javascript, forms, registration, google-forms, web-development-server

using JS .. registeration form then after validation go to log in form then after validation will redirect to quiz page . anyone one know how to make?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the folllowing code to redirect to a different page after validation

window.location.replace("http://sample.com/nexpage");

Comment: please help me if you can 3> :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67578426/how-to-pass-username-and-password-from-page-to-another-using-javascript