# how to pass username and password from page to another using javascript

Tags: javascript, web, cookies, frontend, setcookie

please i want to know how to store the user input data in the registeration page then i pass it to login page and in login page i validate if the user write the right username and password or not(that already passed from registeration page)
here is my js code for registeration page:

```
     <head>
         <script>
             //function to check if the passoword is matched
             function checkpass() {
                 if (document.getElementById('psw').value ==
                     document.getElementById('psw-confirm').value) {
                     document.getElementById('message').style.color = 'green';
                     document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = 'Matched Passowrds';
                 } else {
                     document.getElementById('message').style.color = 'red';
                     document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = 'Those passwords didn’t match. Try again.';
                 }
             }
             //function to disable the submit button if the password is not matched
             function check_pass() {
                 if (document.getElementById('psw').value ==
                     document.getElementById('psw-confirm').value) {
                     document.getElementById('submit').disabled = false;
                 } else {
                     document.getElementById('submit').disabled = true;
                 }
             }
             //function of cancel button
             function goBack() {
                 window.history.back();
             }
             //function to only choose one gendre
             function onlyOne(checkbox) {
                 var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('check')
                 checkboxes.forEach((item) => {
                     if (item !== checkbox) item.checked = false
                 })
             }
    
         </script>
         <link href="RegisterartinStyle.css" rel="stylesheet">
     </head>
```

Comment: You have the cookies tag in your issue. Are you having trouble with cookies? Have you read the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/cookies)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use **sessionStorage** to store temporary data like this...

```
sessionStorage.setItem('Username',username);

sessionStorage.setItem('Password',password);
```

To retreive the data from any of your pages...

```
var Username = sessionStorage.getItem('Username');

var Password = sessionStorage.getItem('Password');
```

Blow everything away...

```
sessionStorage.clear();
```

Comment: Teacher? No, I'm not doing your assignment! Use search engines to research and understand EVERYTHING about cookies.